# How to configure One to many relation in Code First Approach?

Tags: c#

Account Model Class:

```
  [Table("Accounts")]
    public class Account
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
        public float Interval { get; set; }
    }
```

Mobile Model Class:

```
public class Mobile
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string MobileNo { get; set; }
        public virtual Account Account { get; set; }

        public static Mobile Add(string mobile)
        {
            Mobile mobiles = new Mobile();
            mobiles.MobileNo = mobile;

            return mobiles;
        }

    }
```

Here is my action to save new entry:

```
   public ActionResult Register(CompanyAccountViewModel model)
    {
        CancellationTokenSource cancelToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
        CompanyAccountRegistrationRequestMessage requestMessage = new CompanyAccountRegistrationRequestMessage();
        requestMessage.CompanyName = model.Name;
        requestMessage.Interval = model.Interval;
        model.Mobile.ForEach(x=> requestMessage.MobileNo.Add(x));
        Task<CompanyAccountRegistrationResponseMessage> response = _interactor.Handle(requestMessage, cancelToken.Token);

        CompanyAccountViewModel viewModel = _presenter.Handle(response.Result, model, ModelState);
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

_presenter.Handle() method:

```
  public Task<CompanyAccountRegistrationResponseMessage> Handle(CompanyAccountRegistrationRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            CompanyAccountRegistrationResponseMessage returnMessage;
            var validationResult = _validator.Validate(request);
            using (PowerSupplyDBContext dbContext = new PowerSupplyDBContext())
            {
                // ILoginUserCreator loginUsercreator = new LoginUserCreator();
                ICompanyAccountRegistrationUseCase companyAccountregistrationUseCase = new CompanyAccountRegistrationUseCase(dbContext);
                companyAccountregistrationUseCase.RegisterCompanyAccount(request);
                dbContext.SaveChanges();
            }
            returnMessage = new CompanyAccountRegistrationResponseMessage(validationResult);
            return Task.FromResult<CompanyAccountRegistrationResponseMessage>(returnMessage);
        }
```

Here I skip validation right now, i.e: validation is not set:

```
public class CompanyAccountRegistrationRequestMessageValidator : AbstractValidator<CompanyAccountRegistrationRequestMessage>
{
    public CompanyAccountRegistrationRequestMessageValidator()
    {

    }
}
```

***Expectation:*** there is a one to many relation between ***Accounts*** and ***Mobiles*** table, i.e: An Account have many mobile numbers. So there is a Account_Id in ***Mobile*** table and this Account_Id should be filled up with inserted Account ID.

***Actually happening:*** ***Account_Id*** inside ***Mobiles*** table is empty.

[image]

```
Accounts table
```

[image]

```
Mobiles table
```

I am missing something to map before save, This kills my long day. I just started ASP.NET and I am apologizing if  my question is not standard to ask here. Thanks for your time.

**Modification:**
*companyAccountregistrationUseCase.RegisterCompanyAccount(request)*

```
 public void RegisterCompanyAccount(CompanyAccountRegistrationRequestMessage request)
    {
        IList<Domain.Contacts.Mobile> mobiles = new List<Domain.Contacts.Mobile>();

        _companyAccountRegistrationRepo = new CompanyAccountRegistrationRepository(_dbContext);


        Account account = new Account();
        account.CompanyName = request.CompanyName;
        account.Interval = request.Interval;


        foreach (string mobile in request.MobileNo)
        {
            Domain.Contacts.Mobile mobileNo = Domain.Contacts.Mobile.Add(mobile);
            // contact.AssignAccountUser(accountUser);
            mobiles.Add(mobileNo);
        }

        _companyAccountRegistrationRepo.RegisterCompanyAccount(account, mobiles);
    }
```

Comment: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: I read this article but can't figure  out my problem. This article is nice but my level is below average as I just started ASP. Would you suggest me more specific please?

Comment: Do you assign the `Account` property of your `Mobile` instance? Could you show us the code of `companyAccountregistrationUseCase.RegisterCompanyAccount(request);`?

Comment: No, I don't. I just Update my question and share companyAccountregistrationUseCase.RegisterCompanyAccount(request);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to assign the `Account` property of the `Mobile` instance before saving the data to the database. Otherwise, how should the mobile entity know which account it is associated with??

So you should add the following to your `foreach` loop in the `RegisterCompanyAccount` method:

```
mobileNo.Account = account;
```